# My android app crashed after deleting the values-w820dp folder and undoing

Tags: android

I have been following along the tutorial by Android to make the Miwok app. The app has been running okay ever since. However, while I was looking into why there is a black bar above the home button bar, I tried deleting the values-w820dp folder and the app crashed. Even after I undo the change, the app still crashes.

Within the values-w820dp folder, there is only one dimens.xml file and there is a dimension declaration that is never used.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

For some reason, it used to be running okay but a warning appears after I deleted and undid the change:

> The dimen "activity_horizontal_margin" in values-w820dp has no
>   declaration in the base values folder; this can lead to crashes when
>   the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this
>   qualifier.

When I look into logcat, the first two lines of the fatal error says:

> Process: com.example.android.miwok, PID: 21316
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.miwok/com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML
>   file line #16: Error inflating class LinearLayout5

Comment: I can see  MainActivity xml ???

Comment: can you check the main activity XML? There would be some issue in the XML which is causing the error during inflation.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I am a total beginner. I accidently put a "5" after linear layout. So dumb. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in my project. In this case "Clean project" was valid.

> The dimen "margin_large" in values has no declaration in the base values folder; this can lead to crashes when the resource is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier